# Is there a relation between a typography's character width and character height

Tags: python-3.x, python-pptx

I encounter a problem when i use python-pptx, i need to put a line of text to a fixed width textbox and keep it in one line, so i have to calculate the proper font size manually.
The problem is that the font size is determined by character's height, not its width, and i have not found out the relation between its height and width. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

The width of a string in pixels will be approximately some value depending on the text, multiplied by the font size. Approximately, because there may be jumps. A 12 point font might have the exact same width as 11 point, and 13 point might be wider. You might be able to choose 12.4 points which depending on the implementation might be wider or not wider than 12.3 or 12 point.

I suggest that you start by making a wild guess about the best font size based on the length. Sure, WWWWW is a lot wider than iiiii, but for average text it works. You measure the width, then you make a better guess for the best font size.

Comment: Emmm....... seems a feasible workaround, i will give it a try. Thank you! By the way, is it possible to get every character's width and height in a typograph via parsing its corresponding ttf file?